# Windows 10 Pro v1803 unable to join 2008/2003 Domain

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2008, active-directory

**Scenario:**

Domain Controller 1 = Windows 2008 R2

Domain Controller 1 = Windows 2003 R2

- Domain Name = MYCOMPANY (Single Label Domain)
- Functional Level > Windows Server 2003

**Clients:**
Mix of Windows 7 Pro / Windows 10  > 100 qty

Recently we acquired licenses for Win 10 Pro (Downloaded Win 10 ver 1803). When we try to join W10 to domain, it gives error

```
Ac active directory domain controller (AD DC) for the domain "MYCOMPANY" coould not be contacted. 
Ensure that the domain name is typed correctly.
```

Previous version of windows 10 are joined to domain properly. but only this  new version  1803 is not able to join domain.

I can ping domain controller names via effected clients. nslookup working ok.

How can I track the issue? kindly advise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  You have several statements that appear to be incorrect from a technical point of view.  I don't want to make an incorrect assumption.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: It seems a known issue on Windows 10v1803. See this original thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59183715-0c04-44f7-b5ea-bb37da4125a5/unable-to-join-domain-with-new-windows-10-computers-build-1803?forum=win10itpronetworking

Comment: REGEDIT solved the issue

Comment: 1. Start, Run, write regedit,ENTER.
• Lookup this subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters
• Locate AllowSingleLabelDnsDomain. If the key AllowSingleLabelDnsDomain does not exist:
• Edit, New, DWORD.
• Write AllowSingleLabelDnsDomain as key name, and ENTER.
• Double click AllowSingleLabelDnsDomain.
• Set the Value to 1.
2. Exit regedit
3. Try to join the domain

Answer (score 0):

I was able to join WINS, Single Label, NT4 style domain after i reinstalled Windows 10 from old 1511 disk.
Update 1803 is installing back now, and most likely domain will still work after that.

All other methods was ineffective, including: changing various registry options(like *AllowSingleLabelDnsDomain, DNSNameResolutionRequired, DomainCompatibilityMode*), changing network type, adding domain name to hosts file, updating or resetting windows.

Before i had same error and error details was:

```
The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
```